# DAO,BAO files are not reading in custom folder

Tags: extension

I am very much new in the `CiviCRM` . I want to create a custom component , For that I have not tauch the CRM folder I have created my own CTM inside civicrm folder the module name with related `BAO`, `DAO`, `FORM`, `PAGE`,`XM`L, `info.php`, `config.php` and `pseudoconstant.php`. I have loaded CTM_ call to the class loader. My Form folder .php files is working and its loaded the .tpl file also, But DAO,BAO folders .php fils are not loading. can anyone help me out with this problem. I have created my CTM folder inside `sites>all>module>civicrm>CRT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create customizations for CiviCRM you should do so in extensions. You can read more about customizing CiviCRM and creating extension in the [CiviCRM Developer Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/).

You could also check if there is a CiviCRM partner near you on this [list](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) to find out if they are organizing CiviCRM developer trainings you can follow.